# How can i passing data from recyclerview to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I follow a youtube tutorial to write an application. this codes is a part of my recyclerViewAdapter

```
        vHolder.item_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView dialog_name_tv = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name_id);
            TextView dialog_phone_tv = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_phone_id);
            ImageView dialog_contact_img = (ImageView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_img);
            TextView dialog_detail_tv = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_detail);
            dialog_name_tv.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
            dialog_phone_tv.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhone());
            dialog_contact_img.setImageResource(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhoto());
            dialog_detail_tv.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDetail());
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test Click" + String.valueOf(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myDialog.show();
            Button dialog_add_tv = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_add);
            dialog_add_tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText dialog_quantity_tv = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_quantity);
                    quantity = dialog_quantity_tv.getText().toString();
                    name = mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName()+"\n";
                    price = mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhone();
                    Intent i = new 
                    Intent(getActivity(),FragmentFav.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("choices",choices);
                    bundle.putDouble("price",price);
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);


                }
            });

        }
    });



    return vHolder;
}
```

I want to Clicking the dialog_add_tv Button to pass the data to the fragment.class

```
public class FragmentFav extends Fragment {

View v;

public FragmentFav() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call_fragment, container, false);
    return v;

}
```

}

I try many times by using intent still happen error.

Comment: You cannot call `startActivity` on an `Intent` that you're passing your `FragmentFav` to. You need an `Activity` that contains the `FragmentFav`, and you need to start that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using intent you can't open fragment, use below code for open fragment and also pass data to fragment

```
// define a framelayout in activity xml

  <FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/fragment_container"></FrameLayout>

 // then write below code on the click of dialog_add_tv button

 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("choices",choices);
 bundle.putDouble("price",price);

 FragmentFav frgFav=new  FragmentFav();
 frgFav.setArguments(bundle);

 FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTrasaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,frgFav,"frg");
 fragmentTrasaction.commit();


// then get data in fragment like this
 String choice=getArguments().getString("choices");
 String price=getArguments().getString("price");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the step you can follow and implement what you need

Step 1:
Create an interface between adapter and fragment

Step 2: 
Implement an interface in Adapter like this:

```
 vHolder.item_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       mProfileItemClickListener.itemContact(v);
 }
```

// aka Pass the whole view through an interface

Step 3:
In an interface, class add this method

```
void itemContact(View mView);
```

Step 4:
Implement an interface in Fragment:

- Where you will obtain an override method and perform your operation there

  @Override
      public void itemContact(ImageView mProfileImageView) {
      Your code here
      }

You can handle callback properly while passing data between the views.